# How to get feed of a page without 'story'/'story_tags'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to get feed from a page using Graph API, but that feed also contains 'story' like "Page liked a photo" along with status and that story don't have any message.

Because of that empty message, loop runs 3 times (as defined) but if one 'story' comes it returns only 2.

To the point: Is there any 'type' or something to filter that story to fall into the feeds? I want feed free from story generated by users action, specifically 'Liked post' thing.

This is my code:

```
<?php
ob_start();

require_once('fb-sdk/src/facebook.php');

$config               = array();
$config['appId']      = '111111111';
$config['secret']     = '111111111111111111111111';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$pageid = "11111111111111";

$pagefeed     = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/posts");
$page_profile = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "?fields=name");
$pagename     = $page_profile['name'];

echo "<div class=\"fb-feed\">";

$i = 0;
foreach ($pagefeed['data'] as $post) {


    if ($post['type'] == 'status' || $post['type'] == 'link' || $post['type'] == 'photo') {

        if (!empty($post['message'])) {
            echo "<div class=\"fb-update\">";
            echo "<div class=\"fb-pic-name\"><img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/" . $pageid . "/picture\">" . "<span>" . $pagename . "</span></div><p>";
            if (strlen($post['message']) > 70) {
                echo preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($post['message'], 0, 70)) . "&hellip;";
            } else {
                echo $post['message'];
            }
            echo "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/" . $post['id'] . "\" target=\"_blank\"> See More</a></p>";
            echo "<span class=\"date\">" . date("F, jS, g:i a", (strtotime($post['created_time']))) . "</span>" . "<a class=\"comment\" href=\"https://www.facebook.com/" . $post['id'] . "\" target=\"_blank\">Comment</a>";
            echo "</div>";
        }


        $i++;


        if ($i == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }

}

echo "</div>";

ob_flush();
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar answer.  It seems like there should be a way using the API to only gather user generated content posts without "likes" or "comments" but I have been unable to find it either.

Comment: There is. FQL is used to get queried data only, can be used to eliminate nonessential stuff. I just don't know how to use that.

Comment: And the Graph API documentation states clearly that FQL is deprecated and won't be supported moving forward.

Comment: Why dont you use simply {page_id}/posts edge.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i handle this situation in JS :

```
var txt =  response.data[i].message;
if(txt==null){
      txt =  response.data[i].story;
}
alert(txt);
```

In your case, you can "continue" the loop if 'message' is null.

Comment: I don't think that'll work. In order to get next post counter 'i' must be incremented by one. If I continue without incrementing same post will be fetched again.

Comment: so increment 'i' by 1 before continuing the loop.